# Complexity of binary search on contiguous, nonoverlapping segments of an array

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose that we have an $n$ sized array that it broken into $m$ contiguous, non-overlapping chunks such that when the chunks are concatenated, they form the original array.

Say we perform a binary search individually on `chunks[0]`, `chunks[1]`, `chunks[2]`..., `chunks[m-1]`. What is the complexity here? We perform binary search $m$ times. So it seem the cost is

$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} \log (L_i) \\
\sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} L_i = n
$$

where $L_i$ is the length of `chunks[i]`

But how do we write big O in terms of $n$ here?

Answer (score 2):

By Jensen's inequality you have:
$$
\frac{1}{m} \sum \log L_i \le \log \left( \frac{1}{m} \sum L_i \right) =\log\left(\frac{n}{m}\right).
$$
Therefore $\sum \log L_i \le m \log \frac{n}{m}$ and the overall time complexity is $O(m \log \frac{n}{m})$.

Notice that this upper bound is tight (for example when all $L_i$s are roughly equal).